# In NGRX, how do I chain actions from different reducers?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

In my Angular/NGRX application I have two reducers, `reducerA` and `reducerB`.

- `reducerA` retrieves a user ID;
- In `reducerB` i have an action called `GET_ALL_POSTS`.

How can I wait for `reducerA` to resolve before calling `reducerB`.

Comment: I've tried to make the question more clear and general based on feedback/downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this with an effect, you could map the GET_ALL_TRANSACTIONS action when the first one finishes.
eg.

```
retrieveUserId.pipe(
   switchMap((userId) => {
       new GET_ALL_TRANSACTIONS()
   })
)
```

Comment: Thanks Kistijan, I will give this a go. Do you think this ok practice to call the transactions action from within the user reducer? Should I perhaps be creating a seperate action called getInitialData or something similiar?

Comment: Well you could have 2 actions that clearly state when it is called eg. Triggered by *action name* and have a good action hygene. Btw I don't see no other solution in which you can handle your particular scenario.